# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS ios 11.2 swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, ios11.2

I am facing crash in the following code only in iOS 11.2. I am using swift 4.0. I tried to debug for hours to reproduce the crash but could not succeed. Here is the code

```
func prepareNewConnection(conn:String) -> RTCPeerConnection {

    let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

    localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.audioTrack(withTrackId: uuid!)

        mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.mediaStream(withStreamId: LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID)
        if(localAudioTrack != nil && mediaStream != nil)
        {
            mediaStream.addAudioTrack(localAudioTrack!) //Crash on this line
        }

    let pc = peerConnectionFactory.peerConnection(with: rtcConfig, constraints: mediaConstraints, delegate: self)
    if(mediaStream != nil)
    {
        pc.add(mediaStream)
    }

return pc;
}
```

Here is crashlytics report.

[image]

I shall be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Why aren't you properly and safely unwrapping `localAudioTrack` and `mediaStream`?

Comment: Can you give me example? I am not understanding what do you mean by "properly and safely unwrapping". I will be very thankful.

Comment: I am checking both localAudioTrack and mediaStream for nil value.

Comment: But you are not doing it properly. Another thread could set them to `nil`. Safely unwrap them using `if let`.

Comment: Can you write in answer editing my code so that I can accept ? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea if it actually fixes your issue. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: I think this is the root cause of crash.

Comment: I still could not get it. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Read about [Optionals and Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) in the Swift book.

Comment: if let ms = mediaStream{
            if let at = localAudioTrack{
                ms.addAudioTrack(at)
            }
        } Is this correct?

Comment: you can have it this way `if let ms = mediaStream, let at = localAudioTrack { ms.addAudioTrack(at) }` this way you only have one `if-statement`

Answer (score 0):

please avoid safely unwrapping, use if let ..

```
 func prepareNewConnection(conn:String) -> RTCPeerConnection {

   if let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString {
localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.audioTrack(withTrackId: uuid) //removed safely Unwrapping
    mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.mediaStream(withStreamId: LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID)
 let pc = peerConnectionFactory.peerConnection(with: rtcConfig,constraints: mediaConstraints, delegate: self)
    if(localAudioTrack != nil && mediaStream != nil)
    {
        mediaStream.addAudioTrack(localAudioTrack)
        pc.add(mediaStream) 
    }
  }
 return pc
}
```